# String Declaration Error <script>

Tags: javascript, string

I know this is beyond simple but for some reason I'm stuck in a rut with this one. I'm simply trying to declare a string as shown in the code below, however it's generating the following error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

```js
var myString = "<script src='http://some.somedomain.com/some/path/to/some/thing/thing.js'></script>";
```

**Question:** Why is this string declaration throwing the error?

Comment: Is this code inside a `<script>` tag itself?

Comment: you need to escape the end `<\/script>`

Comment: @FelixKling yeah it is, left it out for clarity.

Comment: Leaving it out made the question *less clear*, actually.

Comment: @mplungjan You nailed it, thank god for you lol... quick question though, so I'm writing a bot in C that scans and basically identifies regex patterns  (basically detect external files) so the program won't have the `<\/script` only `</script>` closing tag, any ideas here?

Comment: @Amy sorry for the confusion. Do you have any ideas in regards to the question I just asked right above this comment?